# Как отобразить выбранный элемент swift

Tags: xcode, swift, realm-database

Я делаю приложение новостного портала `swift 2.3` и `xcode 7.3.1.` Использую `Realm`. У меня в `horizontal scroll`  отображаются новости и при нажатии на одну из них мне надо перейти в его детальный вид и отобразить новость в `NewsDetailViewController`. У меня не получается отобразить выбранный элемент и его детальную информацию.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

let realm4 = try! Realm()

class MainViewController: UIViewController, HorizontalScrollDelegate {

let newsObj = realm4.objects(News)
let nObj = News()

var imageURL: NSURL?


override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes

    let hScroll = HorizontalScroll(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 380, 160))
    hScroll.delegate = self
    hScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(hScroll)
    view.reloadInputViews()

}


    func numberOfScrollViewElements() -> Int {
        return newsObj.count
    }



    func elementAtScrollViewIndex(index: Int) -> UIView {

        let indexes = newsObj[index]

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(5.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0))
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        let imageLabel = UIImageView()
        let newsLable = UILabel()
        let button = UIButton()

        var image: UIImage? {

            get { return imageView.image }
            set {
                imageView.image = newValue
                imageView.sizeToFit()
            }
        }


        newsLable.text = indexes.newsTitle

        imageURL = NSURL(string: indexes.newsImage)

        if let url = imageURL {
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            if imageData != nil {
                image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            }
        }

        newsLable.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        newsLable.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 18)
        newsLable.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        newsLable.frame = CGRectMake(7.0, 90.0, 200.0, 50.0)
        newsLable.textAlignment = .Left
        newsLable.numberOfLines = 0

        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapAction2), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.indexOfAccessibilityElement(indexes)
        button.accessibilityElementAtIndex(index)

        imageLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        imageLabel.alpha = 0.45
        imageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 90.0, 200.0, 65.0)
        imageView.frame = view.frame

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(imageLabel)
        view.addSubview(newsLable)
        view.addSubview(button)

        return view
    }


func tapAction2(index2: Int) {
    //let indexes2 = newsObj[index2]
    print("This is func INDEX2 \(index2)")
    let segueIndex = index2
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newView = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailViewController") as! NewsDetailViewController
    newView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
    print("This is nObj \(self.nObj)")
    print("This is INDEX \(index2)")
    newView.newsOfTitle = String(segueIndex)
    presentViewController(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Вот так выглядет `horizontal scroll`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данные в `Realm`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код целевого ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class NewsDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var sliderMenu = SliderMenu()
var newsOfTitle: String?

@IBAction func newsDetailMenuButton(sender: UIButton) {
    showSliderMenu()
}

@IBAction func newsDetailLoginButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let newView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    newView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    self.presentViewController(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func newsDetailSearchButton(sender: UIButton) {


}

@IBOutlet weak var newsDetailImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var newsDetailTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newsDetailFulltext: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {

    newsDetailTitle.text = newsOfTitle

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsController.handleSwipes(_:)))
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        print("Swipe Right")
        dismissView()
    }
}

func dismissView() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func showSliderMenu() {
    sliderMenu.showSliderMenu()
}
}
```

Comment: а можно увидеть только код, который должен отобразить детальную информацию

Comment: Написал код ViewController куда должен переходить

Comment: а можно просто - вот строка кода, она не работает. а то уже две страницы получается

Comment: вот не работающий код: func tapAction2(index: Int) {
        
        
        news2 = realm4.objects(News)
        let new = news2[index] let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newView = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsDetailViewController") as! NewsDetailViewController
        newView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
        newView.newsOfTitle = new.newsTitle
        presentViewController(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: А в main.storyboard у вас указан NewsDetailViewController в поле StoryboardID? http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1610/1b/5e0b71edb98a.png

Comment: **Конечно указано**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с использованием `CollectionViewController` с файлом `XIB`